# How to show randomly generated text and image from a .txt file?

Tags: php, file, random

Here is my code that generates random texts from the `random.txt` file inside a input field.

```
<?php
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "random.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
?>
<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] ); ?>" size="36">
```

Here is the `random.txt` file:

```
USA
UK
Canada
```

I want to show random pictures above the input field:

```
<img src="A random pic"alt="Flags" height="42"width="42">

<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] ); ?>" size="36">
```

And the random.txt will look like this:

```
us_flag.jpg
USA
uk_flag.jpg
UK
ca_flag.jpg
Canada
```

I want this PHP code to randomly show a flag picture above the input field and the country name under the flag picture's file name in the txt file to show inside the input field.

Comment: Side note: Is there a reason in particular as to why you're not using a database for this? It'd make it a lot simpler than working with text files.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I never used database

Comment: I would avoid using a `.txt` file... Either use a DB, or something more structured, like a `.json` or `.xml` file.

Comment: Well, I used to do the same thing years ago and was glad that I took the initiative to learn how to work with databases, it makes things a lot easier :) @user8481790

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 srand(time(null));
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "random.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 if($number_casual%2==0){
    $value = htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual+1] );
    $image = htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] );
 }else{
    $value = htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] );
    $image = htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual-1] );
 }
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
?>
<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" size="36">
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"alt="Flags" height="42"width="42">
```